# Display image in array PHP

Tags: php, image

I know this is a simple question but how can i output an image in an array, for example i have a input field and button, so whenever the user enters data and clicks submit it returns a pop-up window with something like "Thanks for subscribing" etc, i want to replace this text with an image, i have currently tried the following but it is just printing out the path like it is typed.

```
'uk' => array(
                'thanks' => "<img src='../assets/images/ukregisterimg.jpg'>",
                'error' => 'Something went wrong. Please refresh the page and try again.',
                'no_email' => 'Please provide a valid email address.'
            ),
```

Comment: How are you echo'ing this to the user? Can you show that bit of code aswell?

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this? This is no different from accessing info in a multilevel array...

```
echo $array['uk']['thanks'];
```

---

While I'm at it, I suggest you do something like this (the img-part):

```
'uk' => array(
        'error' => 'Something went wrong. Please refresh the page and try again.',
        'no_email' => 'Please provide a valid email address.',
        'img' => array(
                    'src' => "../assets/images/ukregisterimg.jpg"
                    'alt'=> "Some example alt"
                    )
        )
echo '<img src="'.$array['img']['src'].'" alt="'.$array['img']['alt'].' />';
```

That way you can add items in the future, like `width` and `height`, or `title`, without needing to rebuild your whole code

---

For my own knowledge I'd love to know if there is an easy reference in an array to its own values:

```
'img' => array(
    'src' => "../assets/images/ukregisterimg.jpg"
    'alt'=> "Some example alt",
    'html' => '<img src="'.$this->alt.'" alt="'.$this->alt.'" />' // use current array's values dynamicly
    )
```

Comment: No Martijn, you cannot reference the array itself that way :/

Comment: I know that way doesn't work, it was merely a code hint of what I mean to explain. But I'm not aware of a working version of it. Would be cool. I believe that one of the `$_SERVER` values refers via a reference

Comment: I mean you cannot in any way at all ^^ [For instance YAML can](http://yaml.org/spec/history/2001-12-10.html#trans-ptr), but PHP array syntax cannot [thanks god, to some extent].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code that actually outputs this data is escaping it via `htmlentities()` or an equivalent function.  You need to modify the code that actually outputs the string so that it does not escape it.

For example if it says `print(htmlentities($result['uk']['thanks']));` you would change it to just `print($result['uk']['thanks']);`